# TransformIgnorePatterns jest config is not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ts-jest

I have a problem with jest
[image]

After researching, I can resolve it by add transformIgnorePatterns in npm run test script and **it worked**

```
"test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!d3-shape)/\""
```

I try to moving it into jest.config.js file

```js
module.exports = {
  // The root of your source code, typically /src
  // `<rootDir>` is a token Jest substitutes
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],

  // Jest transformations -- this adds support for TypeScript
  // using ts-jest
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },

  // Runs special logic, such as cleaning up components
  // when using React Testing Library and adds special
  // extended assertions to Jest
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    '@testing-library/react/cleanup-after-each',
    '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect',
  ],

  // Test spec file resolution pattern
  // Matches parent folder `__tests__` and filename
  // should contain `test` or `spec`.
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',

  // Module file extensions for importing
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!(d3-shape)/)'],
};
```

and this config **is not working.**

Anyone can provide a help.

Comment: Use the same pattern from the cli and try including `<rootDir>`.

Comment: Try this but not working  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!d3-shape)/'],